# Newbee in Angular, how to use dictionaries?

Tags: arrays, angular, dictionary, ionic-framework, indexing

I'm a C# programmer trying to learn Angular and Ionic.
I'd like to do something as we usually do in C# with dictionaries:

```
export class HomePage {
   private times = [
     {key: 'clockOn',   value: '09:00'},
     {key: 'lunchTime', value: '12:00'},
     {key: 'backToWork',value: '13:00'},
     {key: 'clockOff',  value: '18:00'}
   ];
}

getHour(name: string) {
   if(this.times[name] === 'clockOn'){
      console.log('time: ' + this.times[name].value);
}
```

On HTML

```
<ion-datetime class="time" id="coff" displayFormat="HH:mm" 
   [(ngModel)]="cOff" (ionChange)="getHour('clockOn')">
</ion-datetime>
```

And on Chrome console I see:

> clockOn
> undefined

First of all, is this the correct sintax to access the member 'value'?

```
this.times[0].value
```

I want to know if is it possible to access an array element using a string as indexer (key) like we do in C# with dictionaries

For example:

```
this.times['clockOn'].value //would bring me its value like '09:00'
```

or the only way to access a element is using numbers as indexers? Like below

```
this.times[0].key // bring me 'clockOn'
this.times[0].value // bring me '09:00'
```

Answer (score 1):

Dictionary is Angular/ JavaScript does not work same as C#.

So your code:

```
this.times['clockOn'].value
```

this will not work.

You will have to use

```
this.times[0].key // bring me 'clockOn'
this.times[0].value // bring me '09:00'
```

If you want access with key like array[key] returning the value run the loop in this manner:

```
<td *ngFor="(key, value) in dictionary">
     {{value}}
</td>
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would just modify your data structure, if they are just hardcoded values.

```
  private times = {
        clockOn: '09:00',
        lunchTime: '12:00',
        backToWork: '13:00',
        clockOff: '18:00'
    };

    getHour(key: string)
    {
        if (this.times[name] === 'clockOn')
        {
            console.log('time: ' + this.times[name].value);
        }
    }

    <span *ngFor="(key, value) in times" *ngClick=getHour(key)>{{value}}</span>
```

Having an object with unique keys where you can use bracket notation to look up the desired item is more effective as it allows for quick simple look ups.

If you wanted to use the original data structure you would have to pass in the index of the repeat item so you can access the correct item in the array.

so your mark up would look like this:

<`span *ngFor="time in times" let i=index; *ngClick=getHour(i)>{{value}}</span>`

```
getHour(index: number)
        {
            if (this.times[index].key === 'clockOn')
            {
                console.log('time: ' + this.times[index].value);
            }
        }
```